# How best to deal with libstdc++ dll and libstdc dll when cross-compiling with mingw-w64 using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I'm cross-compiling a C++ (and some C) project from Linux using Mingw-w64 (really using the [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) project), using cmake as the build system. I have come to realise that I need to either provide the dlls libstdc++ and libstdc with the resulting libraries and exe files, or staticly link to these libraries.

My questions are therefore:

1. Which option is preferable, static linking or supplying the files? Personally I prefer the idea of static linking, as it is simpler for the end user in my case.
2. Where can I find the required dlls to supply them if I wanted to (or what steps to create them). I can only find .a versions in my toolchain.
3. How can I instruct cmake to statically link the libraries, bearing in mind that this is only desired for the cross-compile. As a starter, see the toolchain file provided by [MXE](http://mxe.cc/) below, which is what I'm currently using. I would probably not like to modify this, but rather the CMakeLists.txt files, or via a command line cmake option for my release script.

toolchain file

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(MSYS 1)
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gfortran)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres)
set(HDF5_C_COMPILER_EXECUTABLE /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-h5cc)
set(HDF5_CXX_COMPILER_EXECUTABLE /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-h5c++)
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE /opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-pkg-config)
set(QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/qt/bin/qmake)
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32 CACHE PATH "Installation Prefix")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "Debug|Release|RelWithDebInfo|MinSizeRel")
```

Incidentally, I have tried the following cmake invocation, but this made no difference to the binary sizes, so I assumed it didn't work. Tips on actually testing this are welcome, I do have wine installed.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++"" \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/share/cmake/mxe-conf.cmake $WORKING_COPY_DIR/release/xfemm_mingw_win64/cfemm
```

Comment: I wish I had a definitive answer for you. I recently built my version of clang/LLVM for Windows using MinGW-w64. I didn't use cmake. Initially I had a non-static link that wanted the libstdc++ DLL. I know it was non-static because when I ran it under wine it complained about not finding libstdc++.dll. For the life of me I can't remember how I solved the problem (it was two weeks ago, after all), but looking at my yum log I see that I installed the static winpthreads libraries after I did the initial build. I know my final build didn't need the DLL, so maybe that did it? Good luck.

Comment: @RichardPennington, thanks, I should add that I know that you get these dlls when you install Mingw-w64 on windows natively. I but obviously I would prefer to be able to ship them with my program.

Comment: I wanted the same thing. That's why I got my stuff to statically link those libraries. I just wish I could remember how I did it.